# Why do I get a StaleObjectStateException on removing entity?

Tags: java, jpa, spring-boot

In my Spring Boot web app, I have a controller, which provides a method to remove an entity from the database, which in turn calls a DAO class. However, when I call `entityManager.remove(entity)`, I receive a `StaleObjectStateException`, even though `entity` was just retrieved from the database and there was no other call to my API which may have altered `entity`.

This is my controller:

```
@Transactional
@RestController
public class AppAdminController {
    ...
    @RequestMapping(value = "/admins/{username}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public void deleteAdmin(@PathVariable("username") String username) {
        dao.removeByUsername(username);
  }
}
```

DAO:

```
@Service
public class AppAdminDao extends AbstractDAO<UUID, AppAdmin> {

    public AppAdmin getByUsername(String username) {
        TypedQuery<AppAdmin> query = em.createQuery("SELECT a FROM AppAdmin a WHERE a.username=:username", AppAdmin.class);
        query.setParameter("username", username);

        try {
            return query.getSingleResult();
        } catch (NoResultException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void removeByUsername(String username) {
        AppAdmin admin = getByUsername(username);
        if(admin != null) {
              em.remove(admin);
        }
    }
}
```

An `AppAdmin aa` is added by calling

```
AppAdmin res = em.merge(aa);
```

and even calling `em.remove(res)` immediately after adding the entity yields the exception mentioned above. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It could be that your unsaved-value mapping is missing for your entity ?

By the, why don't you just use Spring Data JPA ? Your Dao could be compressed down to this:

public interface ChainLevelRepository extends JpaRepository<AppAdmin, UUID> {}

Comment: How do I add an unsaved-value mapping? I will have a look at Spring Data JPA

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following the hint of PaulNUK, I added an `@Version` annotated field to my entity. Now I received the following exception on adding an entity to my database: `org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1`.

The problem turned out to be the following: My entity has a UUID as an id, which was annotated as follows:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
```

Adding

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)")
```

solved the problem.