# Spring Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect)

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, kotlin

I can't understand, what's wrong with my Service. I receive `org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException` trying to run this method:

```
fun updateNameForPhone(phone: String, name: String): Client {
    val res = clientRepository.findByPhone(phone) ?: throw ClientNotFoundException(phone)

    res.name = name
    return clientRepository.save(res)
}
```

ClientRepository:

```
@Repository
interface ClientRepository : JpaRepository<Client, UUID> {

    fun findByPhone(phone: String): Client?
}
```

Client entity:

```
@Entity
data class Client(
        var name: String = "",
        var phone: String = "",
        @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        val uuid: UUID = defaultUuid()
)
```

Exception:

> Object of class [com.app.modules.client.domain.Client] with identifier
>   [12647903-7773-4f07-87a8-e9f86e99aab3]: optimistic locking failed;
>   nested exception is org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was
>   updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping
>   was incorrect) :
>   [com.app.modules.client.domain.Client#12647903-7773-4f07-87a8-e9f86e99aab3]"

What is the reason?
I'm using Kotlin 1.3.11, Spring Boot 2.1.1, MySql. I don't run it in different threads, just trying with single request.

Comment: can you share how have you defined the transaction here?

Comment: Also, it would be helpful to have database table structure as well

Comment: You get a optimistic lock exception but I don't see that you are using a version field. Can you please post the whole code?

Comment: @simonmartinelli I have no version field, it has not yet been necessity.

Comment: @ankur No transaction and table creations myself, it's incapsulated by Spring. I just tag my Client class with Entity annotation. Service method is called from Controller. There is no interesting code there.

Comment: Here is what i think is the problem: clientRepository.findByPhone(phone) is taking place under transaction T1 while clientRepository.save(res) is taking place under transaction T2. since, your `res` object is part of 2 different transactions, you are facing this issue. Have you used @Transactional anywhere in your code?

Comment: @Ankur Controller's method, which calls service method, is annotated as `Transactional`, but I've deleted this annotation from there and nothing've changed.

Comment: The problem disappears when I change the table identifier type from `UUID` to `Long`.. Looks like something is wrong with UUID and Spring communication.. Btw Long ids are not suitable for me, so I am trying to solve this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, finally I've found a solution. Better say workaround.

The problem is in the way spring uses `UUID` as entity identifier.
So there are two workarounds, solving this issue:

- first, you can change your id field type to other one, such as `Long`, for example, if it's possible to you;
- or you can add this annotation to your `uuid` field: `@Column(columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)")`.

The last solution I've found from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42905256/why-do-i-get-a-staleobjectstateexception-on-removing-entity/42908985) question.