# Row was updated or deleted by another transaction during concurrent job running

Tags: java, postgresql, multithreading, transactions

I'm trying to find an entity from the db, do some modification and then save it, when I run 3-5 jobs at the same time everything works fine, but during concurrent run with 15+ jobs, I see there is always one job failed with `optimistic locking failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException:StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction` and other jobs finished with success. Here is what i want to achieve in my code:

```
  public void myConcurrentRnnningJob(){

  // here the primary key id was generated with an UUID generator  
  Optional<myEntity> entity = repository.findById(request.getId());

  log.info("found entity");

  myEntity.ifPresent(entity -> {

            //set some values in entity, then save
            ...
            
            log.save("saving entity");

            repository.save(entity);  <- this line is printed in the error log

        });
```

I noticed that when the exception is thrown, both "found entity" and "saving entity" logs have the exact same timestamp, and
my findById() and save() methods are:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
@Repository
public interface RequestsRepository extends CrudRepository<Request, UUID>) {
    
    @Override
    Optional<RequestEntity> findById(UUID id);
   
    @Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
    @QueryHints({ @QueryHint(name = "javax.persistence.lock.timeout", value = "-2") }) // skip locked
    @Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    <T extends RequestEntity> T save(@NotNull T entity);
}
```

I don't know why the above error happens and if the issue is caused by saving and finding the record at the same time.

Comment: The exception is clearly saying what's happening: 2 or more transactions retrieved the same entity. When they finished, the second one will fail. Try doing some research on hibernate/JPA optimist lock. If it's required that your jobs "never fail", then optimistic lock may not be the correct approach.

Comment: @VitorSantos I've found a workaround from other questions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54060522/spring-row-was-updated-or-deleted-by-another-transaction-or-unsaved-value-mappi/